# Unable to search data in nested html elements inside react-table cells

Tags: reactjs, react-table

This table has a few cells with simple texts in the name and age columns, and a few with texts inside HTML elements in the details column. The code below can search for texts in the name and age columns, but not in the details column.

```
import { useTable, useGlobalFilter } from "react-table";

const data = [
  { name: "Sam", age: 25 },
  { name: "Emily", age: 21 }
];

const columns = [
  { Header: "Name", accessor: "name" },
  { Header: "Age", accessor: "age" },
  { Header: "Details", accessor: "details" }
];

const Table = () => {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state,
    setGlobalFilter
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data
    },
    useGlobalFilter
  );

  const { globalFilter } = state;

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={globalFilter || ""}
        onChange={(e) => setGlobalFilter(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Search..."
      />

      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                      {cell.column.id === "details" ? (
                        <div>
                          <p>Some nested content for {row.original.name}</p>
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        cell.render("Cell")
                      )}
                    </td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-nested-elements-search-8ghskd) is the live demo.

I want to make it possible to search the cells with HTML elements too.

Comment: Look into using the `useRef` hook to access DOM elements. Here's a resource you can go through [useRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef)

Comment: @SebastianGbudje Can you show me an example?

Comment: I would honestly avoid using useRef it's generally not best practice to manipulate the DOM. You'll have to come up with hacky fixes to update your useRef variable since it won't update automatically, you have to make a reference to every single element in your DOM. It's also a bad idea performance wise.

Comment: Working on an example for you

Comment: I have solved the issue. I will post the solution soon.

Comment: here's a rough example of how to use `useRef` the problem with this is you will not be able to filter out the DOM unless you update it with the `filteredItems` and that isn't going to be easy.  [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-night-8kgz6c?file=/src/App.js)